# initial-scale = 1.0 + width= device-width not fitting the whole screen on any mobile

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive website using the theme Delicate. It comes in built with the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1" />
```

Which I was under the impression would set the entirety of the content on the screen width. On my phone I have to zoom out to have the content displayed somewhat nicely. I've tried changing the initial-scale value to 0.65 which made the site look nice on my personal phone which I am using to develop but it doesn't work well on the iphone 6 or other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the main container which has a fixed width, instead of adaptive width based on screen. My guess is that the theme is crap!

Here's a fix:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0pt; 
  padding: 0pt;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-pad {
  width: 100%;
}
```

To be more specific, you'd have to apply this rule only to small devices like so:

```
/* Apply this width only to small devices */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .content-pad {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Make sure you either change the theme' default width or append `!important` on the width because of css specificity.

Answer (score 0):

initial-scale=1 seems to break more than it fixes. I just use:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
```

Which gives me the hoped-for matching to width. Desktop browsers are fine, Android on Chrome is now perfect in both orientations, as is Silk on a Kindle.
Haven't tested on IOS (which is the new IE6, IMHO), but I'll be hacking in a specific fix for that if I need to.