# Website zoomed in on samsung phones

Tags: android, html, css

So I'm building a webpage trying to learn some basic webdesign. My problem right now is that on samsung-phones (according to the developer tools, and my samsung phone) the page starts a little bit zoomed in:
[image]

I can instantly make it ok by pinch-zooming out, but I feel there should be some way to have it start like that.

Annoyingly (or thankfully) this doesn't seem to happen to any of the other devices in the developer tools. I do have the following in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
```

Do anyone have any idea as to why this is and if it's fixable? It kind of ruins the first impression and I know a lot of people with samsung phones.

EDIT: It also returns to the slightly zoomed in state every time you click on a link making it hard to navigate around the site.

Here's a [link](http://libnef.pythonanywhere.com) to the page if that would help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527671/initial-scale-1-0-width-device-width-not-fitting-the-whole-screen-on-any-mo check if this link is helpful

Comment: Thanks looking into it right away!

Comment: Yes that fixed it! For some reason (which I no longer remember) I set a min width to a content-element, it was set to 400px which only the samsung phone goes below. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Turns out I can only accept my answer in 2 days. If you want to copy my answer (or write it in your own words). I'll delete mine and tag yours as accepted.

Comment: Just to add I highly recommend looking into bootstrap when doing css for mobile devices

Comment: Interesting, right now I'm mostly using flex-boxes for layout. I thought bootstrap was only for pretty-fying your elements, like nice tables, forms and buttons and stuff? Gotta look into it again I suppose :)

Comment: Alright, now I've read about their grid system and it sounds exactly like what I need for the page (it's even built with flexboxes so it shouldn't be that hard to change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a container-element holding most of the web-page having "min-width: 400px" only causing problem on the samsung phone since all the other phones have screen widths above 400px.

edit : Copied the answer from the link i shared